# jQuery function import

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a problem with js function import. For example I'm using gmaps.js.
I added this library in pages. And I have main.js file and calling this script with this way

```
var map = new GMaps({
    el: '#map',
    lat: 40.783435,
    lng: -73.966249
});
map.addMarker({
    lat: 40.784076,
    lng: -73.966332,
    icon: "img/mapicon.png",
    title: 'Marker with InfoWindow',
    infoWindow: {
        content: '<p>Central Park</p>'
    }
});
```

In contact.html has a #map div but services.html not. And other js functions not working on services.html. I'm using a lot of library and just call on contact.html page is not solution for me. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why dont you check what page your are viewing and only execute the code if you're viewing the right page?

Comment: Because I'm using 1.js on a,b,c pages and 2.js on b,c,d page and this way not a good solution for me

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the difinition of AMD, one of the libraries that implements this methodology is require.js

You can start reading here:
http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html

Give both of these a shot on Google.

Then again, if you run into circular dependencies perhaps there is something erong with your implementation.

I will be more than glad to help with anything else.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try to check if `#map` exists first? If it exists, then initialize GMaps :)

```
// Will return true when the element #map exists
if($("#map").length) {
    var map = new GMaps({
        el: '#map',
        lat: 40.783435,
        lng: -73.966249
    });
    map.addMarker({
        lat: 40.784076,
        lng: -73.966332,
        icon: "img/mapicon.png",
        title: 'Marker with InfoWindow',
        infoWindow: {
            content: '<p>Central Park</p>'
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I have a lot of libraries and functions if I use this it'll be like a horror movie :))

Comment: What about my solution then?